# python adding a new line to the existing line

Tags: python, file

I tried every possible thing to add a new line at the end of the existing line, but i am not getting what i exactly need.

**Coding:**

```
def retrieve_input(self):
    input1 = self.txt1.get("0.0",'end-1c')
    with open('text.txt','r+') as f:
        f.write(input1+" -d")#<-gettting wrong input
```

**My file:**

```
Hello ,how are you.
```

After adding a new line to input 1: "are you fine?"

Then it has to add as:

```
Hello ,how are you.
are you fine?
```

Please ,help me to fix it!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what it is you expect that code to do. Where is the rest of the class? What is the `'-d'` for?

Comment: it a long code,so i just took the wrong part.I used '-d' from seeing a 'python mail' website,but its not helping!

Comment: Please provide a runnable [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, not just a random snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 with open('text.txt','a+') as f:
        f.write(input1+" -d")#<-gettting wrong
```

Comment: the prob is i should not get '-d',please help to me avoid display -d!

Comment: @user3914506 ...don't include `'-d'`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe without adding '-d' its not going to the new line,its just adding to the same line!

Comment: @user3914506 then use `'\n'`, the newline character.

Comment: @jonrsharpe \n also  adding to the same line,my only prob is i need to delete '-d' after using!

Comment: @jonrsharpe now only my foolish head got what you said ,instead of '\n' is used '/n',thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

**An example is enigmatic, I can only guess what it is.**

My test file:

```
first line
second line
third line
```

My code:

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
         print line+'\n'
```

Output:

```
first line


second line


third line
```

If you are using Windows [change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) `\n` to `\r\n`

Comment: @user3914506 Next time try to explain - I do not have a magic bullet but a desire to help

Comment: i appreciate for your help!